# Which directory contains third party libraries for Spark

Tags: apache-spark

When we use

```
spark-submit
```

which directory contains third party libraries that will be loaded on each of the slaves?  I would like to scp one or more libraries to each of the slaves instead of shipping the contents in the application uber-jar.

Note: I did try adding to

```
$SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars
```

But the `spark-submit` still results in a `ClassNotFoundException` for classes included in the added library.

Comment: You need to put the full log error.

Comment: How can I answer this last question? Let's say that in order to help you with your issue. We need more specific information about how you submit your job and what actual error it is giving you. ClassNotFoundException is not enough. We are not fortune tellers :-)

Comment: Can we start with answering this question: "Is there a third party jar directory"?  I would be surprised if the answer were "no". In that case we have to ship all classes every time a new job were submitted.  I do see "datanucleus" jars in the lib_managed/jars directory.

Answer (score 4):

Hope these points will help you.

$SPARK_HOME/lib/ [contains the jar files ]

$SPARK_HOME/bin/ [contains the launch scripts - Spark-Submit,Spark-Class,pySpark,compute-classpath.sh  etc]

Spark-Submit ---will call ---> Spark-Class.
Spark-class internally calls compute-Classpath.sh before executing / launching the job.

**compute-Classpath.sh** will pick the jars availble in $SPARK_HOME/lib to CLASSPATH.
(execute ./compute-classpath.sh //returns jars in lib dir)

So try these options.

- option-1 - Placing user-specific-jars in $SPARK_HOME/lib/ will works
- option-2 - Tweak compute-classpath.sh so that it will be able to pic
  your jars specified in a user specific jars dir

Comment: Those sound like promising approaches.  I think yes they should work. Will report back later today.